# Jquery Dialog Event repeat triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog, repeat

I am opening a calendar plugin in jquery dialog.

The issue I had been facing is whenever I close the dialog and reopen back, my calendar event `onDayClick` will trigger twice. If repeat will trigger 3 times and so on.

```
<div id="show_calendar">
    <div class="custom-calendar-wrap">
    <div class="custom-header clearfix">
         <nav>
    <span id="custom-prev" class="custom-prev"></span>
    <span id="custom-next" class="custom-next"></span>
         </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="calendar" class="fc cw-calendar-container"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
$(function(){
    //OpenCalendar
    $('.open-calendar').on('click', function() {
        var cal = calendar_wall();
        $('#show_calendar').dialog('open');

        return false;
    });
});

$('#show_calendar').dialog({
    width:'75%', 
    height:'800', 
    title:'Select Tour Date', 
    autoOpen:false, 
    modal:true ,
    open: function(event, ui) {
    },      
    buttons: {
    'Submit' : function() {  
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
} });

function calendar_wall(){
    var cal = $( '#calendar' ).calendarWall( {
                onDayClick : function( $el, dateProperties ) {
                console.log("A");
                });

    //Nav
    $( '#custom-next' ).unbind("click").bind("click", function() { 
        console.log("B");
    } );
    $( '#custom-prev' ).unbind("click").bind("click", function() {
        console.log("C");
    } );

    return cal;
}
</script>
```

Calling `calendar_wall()` outside the click event will not cause repeat triggering. But my webpage is ajax style so open calendar button will be click a lot of time which in the end become slow due stacking.

:::::UPDATE:::::

Ok I just found out rebind back the next and prev year button will solve the issue.
What left now is the onDayClick event will still trigger repeatedly. I add up plugin code below.

```
$.CalendarWall.defaults = {
            monthNames : shortMonthName,
            dayNames  : DayName,
            onDayClick : function( $el, dateProperties ) { return false; }
};

$.CalendarWall.prototype = {    
...
...

_initEvents : function() {
    var self = this;
        //How do i add unbind and bind here??
    this.$el.on( 'click.calendarWall', 'td', function() {

        var $cell = $( this ),
            idx = $cell.index(),
            dateProp = {
                day : $cell.children('span.date').text(),
                weekdayname : $cell.children('span.weekday').text(),
                month: $cell.closest('table').find('th.cw-month > span.month').text(),
                monthname: $cell.closest('table').find('th.cw-month > span.monthname').text(),
                year : self.year                    
            };

        if( dateProp.day ) {
            self.options.onDayClick( $cell, dateProp );
        }

    } );
},

}
```

:::: UPDATE 2 ::::

Adding this line to the plugin event no longer have the issue.

```
this.$el.off('click.calendarWall').on( 'click.click.calendarWall', 'td', function() {
```

Comment: show code for `calander_wall()`. Sounds like it reinitalizes calander

Comment: can't you initialize calander within ajax callback whenever you change it's html?

Comment: can you show me some example?

Comment: post sample of ajax that loads into calander

Comment: issue fixed, by adding off and on into the event.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you are calling `calendar_wall` as many times as the `open-calendar` element is clicked which will register a new click handler along with existing one each time.

A possible solution to check whether the `calendar_wall` was already called for the current `#calendar` instance if so don't do anything.

```
function calendar_wall() {
    var $calendar = $('#calendar');
    if ($calendar.data('calendar_wall')) {
        return;
    }

    $calendar.data('calendar_wall', true)
    var cal = $calendar.calendarWall({
        onDayClick: function ($el, dateProperties) {
            console.log("A");
        }
    });
    //Nav
    $('#custom-next').on('click', function () {
        console.log("B");
    });
    $('#custom-prev').on('click', function () {
        console.log("C");
    });

    return cal;
}
```

Comment: I actually want to reinitialize the calendar